# Jumping from a scope

Tags: c++, scope, break, goto, continue

Is it possible to jump from an unnamed scope?

```
void MyFunc() {
    {
        ... // Code

        if (!head_size) {
            goto _common_error; // <- break and continue don't work here
        }

        ... // Code

        if (!tail_size) {
            goto _common_error; // second time
        }

        ... // Code
    }

    _common_error:
    {
        ... // Code
    }
}
```

My question is not whether this can be redesigned, but whether there is a trick in c++ that I don't know.

Is there a mechanism in c++ other than goto to jump out of an unnamed scope? break and continue do not work in scopes.

Update1: changed word namespace to scope

Comment: What are you trying to do? I have a feeling that you mean a *scope*, rather than an *unnamed namespace*. Can you give a more complete example? In C++, it is very rare to find cases when a `goto` is a reasonable solution. Maybe you want a `return` statement?

Comment: break only works in a loop or switch.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Most likely your code should be redesigned

Comment: Please post a [mcve] (code fragments don't count). And there is no namespace in the posted code.

Comment: @Rakete111 i have changed namespace to scope in my question

Comment: @macroland coming from the guy called "macroland" :p

Comment: Depending on your meaning, which is still unclear, there are options.  Throwing exceptions can pass control to a caller (or, more accurately, the first caller that can catch the thrown exception), but also unwinds the stack (e.g. cleans up variables of automatic storage duration).     There are also function `setjmp()` and `longjmp()`.   Calling `exit()` or `abort()` terminates the program - which, by definition, causes control to leave the current scope.  A `return` statement passes control to the caller (which is a different scope).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you need to use `goto` to jump out of a scope.

`break` can only be used to jump out of a loop or switch.

But you can use a (questionable) trick by using a dummy loop:

```
void MyFunc() {
    do {
        ... // Code

        if (!head_size) {
            break;
        }

        ... // Code

        if (!tail_size) {
            break;
        }

        ... // Code
    } while (false);

    {
        ... // Error handling code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using macro magic

```
#define BREAKABLE_SCOPE() for (char __scope = 0; __scope == 0; __scope++)
```

You can then do

```
int main()
{
    // Will only print "Hello!"
    BREAKABLE_SCOPE()
    {
        printf("Hello!");
        break;
        printf("Hello again!");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Please note that macros will reduce the readability of your code.